# Parameters of Variant calling analysis

Tags: bioinformatics, dna-sequencing, genomics, snp

What is the good or stringent parameter for variant calling?
At present using the DP > 10 and Q > 30 for Variant calling. Is it ok?

Comment: What tool are you using and what are you calling on, whole genome, exome?

Comment: @CMosychuk, its Whole genome sequencing

Answer (score 2):

We will be needing some additional information to answer your question more completely:

What sequencing platform are you using? `Illumina HiSeq/MySeq`; `Ion proton`

What type of sequencing ([as noted by @CMosychuk](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/48423/parameters-of-variant-calling-analysis/48447#comment84990_48423)): `Exome` or `Whole Genome`?

What type of variant caller ([as noted by @CMosychuk](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/48423/parameters-of-variant-calling-analysis/48447#comment84990_48423)): `Unified Genotyper`; `Haplotype Caller`; `TVC`

The `QUAL` metric is heavily dictated my sequencing depth, so if you use `30` (phred-scaled), that would be an accuracy of `99.9%`.

The typical `QUAL` metric used by most sequencing studies is `20` so using `30` may cause accumulation of false negatives. But again, depends on the type of sequencing and platform used.

Comment: this looks more like a comment than an answer - once you have earned some more reputation points you will be able to comment anywhere, but until then please refrain from commenting as an "answer" - thanks for your contribution!

Comment: @VanceLAlbaugh I won't classify this as a comment outright, the latter parts of the answer are in fact answers to the question.

Comment: @MarchHo I'll take your word for it - not obvious to me (an outsider in that specific field)

Comment: Its whole genome sequencing, Illumina HiSeq 1000 platform, Type of cariant caller is Unified genotyper. Tools using samtool, vcftool.

Comment: For variant filter using SNPeff

Comment: Try sticking with a `QUAL` of `20`. Illumina usually produces well-mapped reads. If you think some of the lower quality variants are artifacts, try sanger sequencing them and see if they validate. A `QUAL` of `30` seems high for Illumina data.